# What is registry equivalent for Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, file, registry, ini

Recently I have been involved in **code porting from Windows to a Linux**. I came across so many windows functions which retrieve registry keys and edit it. I am not sure what can be the equivalent approach for Linux. I know registry is just a windows database which stores data in **"Key=value"** format. I am thinking about **INI file**. Other than this is there anything that is more efficient?

I am **not asking from a storage perspective**. My question is related to registry equivalent in Linux. **How can we achieve registry structure in Linux?**

Comment: If your application needs to modify these values on the fly, a SQLite database could be an effective solution.

Comment: @cdhowie Every time if I need to retrieve any value, ain't there will be overhead in opening and closing database?

Comment: Not if you retain a database handle for the life of the application. SQLite handles are not thread-safe, however; access to the same handle must be properly synchronized. It is, however, possible to safely use multiple handles to the same database file in parallel. Consider having a handle per thread, or a handle pool that threads can borrow from.

Comment: Hmmm, apart from that is there any other method? Because I don't want to make things complex. I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: SQLite is considerably simpler, in my opinion, than parsing an .ini file and rewriting the whole thing every time something changes. Some kind of key-value store is the closest analog to the Windows Registry. I mean you could throw up a Redis server, too, if you think that's simpler...

Comment: @cdhowie Now as we are discussing SQLite Database. Nowadays I am hearing more and more about MongoDB. How about using it instead SQLite? Any thoughts?

Comment: SQLite is an in-process library. That is, it runs inside of your application. MongoDB is an external database server (similar to SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.). If MongoDB gives you some advantage, then use it. But of course it requires separate install and configuration, where SQLite requires zero configuration.

Comment: Ok. MongoDB will be cumbersome in that case. SQLite seems good as its in-process library. I need to do some POC's in that case.Thanks anyway for your suggestions @cdhowie

Comment: [Keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Don't use a storage scheme more complex than needed to store your data. There is no need to add dependencies to some SQL-based product just to store the fact that the user likes a blue background.  In that case, something like a key-value text-based properties file is awfully simple...

Comment: @cdhowie, Sqlite is good in theory but bad in implementation. Never touch sqlite: Use portable mysql distros.

Comment: @Pacerier I would use flat text files before using MySQL.

Comment: @cdhowie, ? MySQL portable is really great, self-contained, and require no installation. What's wrong?

Comment: @Pacerier (1) Requiring a separate RDBMS process just to manage your config is silly -- you should be able to do this all in-process, which SQLite does, (2) if you are going to use an RDBMS, there are much better options than MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

A typical way to store configuration in Linux per user is to store it in `/home/username/.someapp`, where `someapp` is the name of your program. I love this in Linux actually because when I move to another computer, all I have to do is save/move my home directory, and that will save all my configuration.

On Windows, the registry has a user part `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, and others that represent any user, such as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, being global for the whole system. For the user part, you should put the configuration in the user directory like I explained before, because it shouldn't require any super-user privileges. The local machine part you can choose either to also put in the user directory, where then every user will have separate configuration, or put it in something like `/var/lib/someapp`, but keep in mind that it'll be read-only then.

With all this, keep in mind that you should create your own configuration format, or use some library, such as [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/), XML or JSON.

Comment: I am not asking about its storage. Anyway, don't you think there will be overhead in parsing XML or JSON? Rather than this, we can use a simple INI file.

Comment: @sonugupta What to use is a different question. You can use an ini file, sure. In fact, if you're worried about performance, go ahead and use Google Protocol Buffers. It's made for network communication and has super-efficient serialization. My recommendation is not to worry about performance of reading config files because it's absolutely nothing compared to anything useful you're gonna do in the program. I don't imagine you have 500 MB of configuration.

Comment: Isn't the new convention to store settings inside `/home/<username>/.config/<your_file>`?

Answer (score 3):

Linux has [XDG Base Directory](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory_support) specification. If you want to use config file(s) for your app (doesn't matter which format you prefer - INI, JSON, YAML, SQLite database, etc), please store it in directory `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/your_app_name`

Comment: Ahh. This is not a relevant answer.I am not asking from a storage perspective. My question is related to registry equivalent in Linux. How we can achieve registry structure in Linux?

Comment: @sonugupta *This is not a relevant answer.* Yes, it is relevant.  You need to know **where you can store your data**.

Comment: Its not about WHERE I can store data, Its about HOW I can save the data.

Answer (score 0):

Usually many software take the config files in the `/etc`, but it's a static configuration as I think. If you have something changed configuration from the software (by user or after something external) it's good idea to put it into `/var/lib/(your_project_short_name)/(your_project_config_files)` I suppose, as it do Mysql, Postgresql for the database files and the Postgresql's config files etc.